# XSLT, obtain all descendant text nodes except one

Tags: xml, xslt

Have such transformation that should obtain all descendant text nodes, except descendant element `mslTTSRepl`, instead of it i want to obtain the value of its `@repl`.
`

```
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template  match="text()"/>

<xsl:template match="//*[contains(@role, 'tts') and @xml:id]">
    <xsl:variable name="allText">
        <xsl:copy-of select=".//text()[not(ancestor::mslTTSRepl)]|.//mslTTSRepl/@repl"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="item">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="@xml:id"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy-of select="normalize-space($allText)"/>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="//*[contains(@role, 'tts') and not(@xml:id)]">
    <xsl:message>There is elements with role="tts" but without Id.</xsl:message>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="tts">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

`

Example input:
`

```
<para role="tts" xml:id="qwe">One text 
   <d> another text<h>third text</h></d> 
   <mslTTSRepl repl="replace text">unness text</mslTTSRepl>
    last text
</para>
```

Output example:

```
<tts>
    <item id="qwe">One text another text third text replace text last text</item>
</tts>
```

But now it returns run-time error

```
Error at xsl:copy-of on line 19 of file:/D:/projects/msl/tools/msl.framework/tts.xsl:
Cannot write an attribute when there is no open start tag
Transformation failed: Run-time errors were reported
```

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: @michael.hor257k 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to copy an attribute into a variable - and you have no element to serve as the attribute's parent. Try changing this:

```
<xsl:variable name="allText">
        <xsl:copy-of select=".//text()[not(ancestor::mslTTSRepl)]|.//mslTTSRepl/@repl"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

to:

```
<xsl:variable name="allText">
    <xsl:for-each select=".//text()[not(ancestor::mslTTSRepl)]|.//mslTTSRepl/@repl">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, f*cked with it for two days!